# How to get HttpStatusCode or why StatusCode is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular Client and I do a List request like this.

```
getMyList(body: SearchCriteria): Observable<HttpResponse<MyResult[]>> {
  return this.http.post<HttpResponse<MyResult[]>(url,body);
}
```

And I execute this with

```
httpService.getMyList(body).subscribe((response: HttpResponse<MyResult[]>) =>
{
 console.log(response.body)
 console.log(response.status)
 console.log(response.statustext)
 console.log(response)
}
);
```

Console Output of this is:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
[{my list....}]
```

So my question, why is "response" directly my list and not a HttpResponse. How to get the statuscode?

My expectaion was.

```
response.body  // is my list result
response.status //is a HttpStatusCode
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the [Angular documentation for `post`, specifically Overload #13, which returns the object as T, along with the `HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#overload-13-6)

Comment: #13 is like copy paste of my code, how this can help me?

Comment: Where does your code specify the `observe: "response"` option? Or the `responseType: "json"` option? That example also shows `T` as being the type of the JSON being returned, so it would be called using `post<MyResult[]>`, not `post<HttpResponse<MyResult[]>>`

Comment: If you read my comment and the documentation again, you'll find that it's called with `post<MyResult[]>` and returns an `Observable<HttpResponse<MyResult[]>>`. Again, you'll have to pass the correct `options` object as the third parameter to `post`. `response.body` will be typed as `MyResult[]`. See [this Stackblitz for an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcuwe8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (it doesn't actually work [i.e., make a request], but it shows that the code compiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass options object with the `http.post`, similar to the following:

```js
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' }
  );
}
```